# How do I make the initial state of an LSTM trainable in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I am working in Keras, and I have an LSTM for which I specify an `intial_state=h0`. Now, I want that `h0` to be a trainable variable. How can I do that?

[A similar question was asked for TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48942422/making-a-trainable-initial-state-for-an-lstm-in-tensorflow), but I am sure that the right way to do this in Keras does not imply an `import keras.backend as K` and hacking Keras classes.

Currently my ugly solution consists in using a dummy input equal to 0 and learning the inital state as the output (= layer bias, since I give a dummy input=0) of a Dense layer with input given by the dummy input:

```
dummy_inp = Input((1,), name='dummy_inp')
dummy_inp_zero = Lambda(lambda t: t*0)(dummy_inp) # to ensure that the input=0
layer_h0 = Dense(dim_lstm_state, bias_initializer='zeros')
lstm_network = LSTM(n_units, bias_initializer='zeros', return_sequence=True)

h0 = layer_h0(dummy_inp_zero)
```

This works, but it is really ugly. Is there any elegant way to do this?

Thank you in advance for the kind help!

Comment: Well if there isn't a keras layer to support this, you have your write your own layer. But this will be very similiar to "hacking keras classes". While this is propably the most complicated solution to implement(and it seems like this is not the answer you're looking for). It's the most clean solution from the usage perspektive, because now you can use your own lstm layer like the standard lstm layer in keras. Your ugly solution might actually the easiest solution to implement (also you can wrap this up in a layer, too)

Answer (score 3):

can look for more detail here https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html

```
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_inputs,
                                     initial_state=encoder_states)
```

Comment: This is a completely different problem from the one I am trying to solve. In seq2seq models the intial state of the decoder is not a learnable parameter, it is instead given by the last hidden state of the encoder.

Comment: that not right ... the encoder is learning with the decoder .. you dont have to put them in different models.. please read the article